# simple shell for multiple commands in a line

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, system-calls

my program should print out a prompt: myshell> when it is ready to accept input. It must read a line of input, accepting several possible commands. This is a very simple shell, so it only accepts two command: run and exit.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


 int h=0;
  void keep(int sig){
  h=1;
 }
 int main()
 {
 signal(SIGINT,keep);//gets into the interrupt
    while(1)
 {
 printf("myshell>");
 char line[255];
 fgets(line, 255, stdin);
 if(!strcmp(line,"\n")){//checks if the given line is not empty
    continue;
  }
    if(h)
    {
    h=0;
    continue;
    }
  int g = 0;
  char *words[5];
  words[g] = strtok(line," \n");//Tokenize the given line
   while (words[g]!=NULL)//splitting the tokens
  {
   g++;
   words[g] = strtok(NULL," \n");
   }
  if(strcmp(words[0],"run")==0)
  {
   int status;
   printf("myshell:Started child pid %d \n",getpid());
   pid_t result = fork();
   printf("myshell:Started child pid %d \n",getpid());
   if(result>0)
   {
   wait(&status);//gets into the wait state
   }
   else if  (result == 0)//new child process created
   {
   char *args[3];
   int k=0;
   while(k<4)//take the whole string into array and execute
   {
     args[k] = words[k+1];
     k++;
   }
   int output;
   output = execvp(*args,args);
   if(output==-1)
   {
     printf("myshell: could not find the program %s\n",words[1]);
   }
   }
   }
  else if(strcmp(words[0],"exit")==0)//comparing with the exit
  {
   exit(1);
   }
   else
   {
   printf("myshell: %s is not a valid command\n",words[0]);
   }
   }
   return 0;
   }
```

it works good with

```
./myshell
 myshell> run ls
 myshell: started child pid 7973
 myshell myshell.c
```

MY shell should support using ; to execute multiple programs with a single command. To make it simple, let's assume there is a space before and after the ;. For example:

```
 ./myshell
 myshell> run ls -l ; date ; who
```

But this is not working with this code.

Comment: You need *two* tokenizing stages: One to split each line on semicolon, and then another for each command (like the one you have now). Important note: The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is *not* reentrant, you can not have two nested `strtok` loops tokenizing different things.

Comment: You and [raju](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6869665/raju) should get together — your code is remarkably similar to the code in his [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730670/simple-shell-for-multiple-commands-in-a-line).

Comment: I'm going to ignore the fact that you self-plagiarized and assume you know that's not a good thing to do and are in the process of deleting the extra question. However, your questions still have one problem. Specifically, **[edit] your question to remove your entire code, and contain only a [mcve]**.